# What is a vertical panorama called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, geography

A mountain “viewpoint” is a great place to get a panoramic view of a region: you can generally take in a huge area [*panorama*] from left to right.

I was wondering what term or phrase describes a similar view from a point on earth to point a way above it. In a gorge, perhaps, you don't get much of a panorama, but you might see a mountain at the end of it.

I want to use it in a sentence like...

> Headstone is the best spot in this valley to enjoy an epic "vertical sight" of 4500 meters from the riverbed to the summit of the mighty Mt. Tumbledown.

Comment: Hello, Shy Snail. Please help us by quoting a dictionary definition supporting 'Sightline is **how far** you can see from a point on earth surface to another object on the earth' (indicating a maximum distance). All I can find are variations on 'any of the straight lines of unimpeded vision from various points' (so a line, not a maximum length) (this definition in [Webster's New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sightline)).

Comment: A person on a mountain has the greater *field of view,* perhaps. The maximum vertical distance that can be viewed is from the horizon (or objects on the horizon, including distant hills) to the zenith, directly overhead. I'm not entirely sure how the word you want would be used. Could you [edit] your question to give a real-world example?

Comment: The question edit suggests to me that OP is looking for a word to describe a panorama but in the vertical sense. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vertorama) online dictionary has **vertorama** but its usage is for a photograph, not a view.

Comment: I think the OP's edit made the intent clear, although retaining *sightline* was distinctly unhelpful because it gave the word a meaning it doesn't really have. @WeatherVane's "vertical panorama" is helpful though. ShySnail, does the question now ask what you wanted?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well...your edit makes my answer  look rather  foolish, and was not in the original i.e. "A mountain “viewpoint” is a great place to get a panoramic view of a region" Essentially it answered the Q...

Comment: @Cascabel That's because the OP had used *sightline* to mean *panorama* or *field of view*, which it doesn't really. But ShySnail can comment or even roll back.

Comment: @AndrewLeach _de acuerdo_. I had to look up their usage in image search and none seemed to match the idea they were trying to define...hence my caveat...That said, there may be a good question here...but I am not sure your revisions are clarifying the issue,. In the meantime, I will let this Q percolate.

Comment: I agree that 'field of view' seems more appropriate for the example sentence. Both 'sight line' and 'line of sight' mean different things. The former is applied to how the view at a road junction etc is limited, the latter as descriptive of the path of sight to a particular object.

Comment: Please don't give answers in comments. Write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

***view***

> **2**. a sight or prospect, typically of attractive natural scenery, that can be taken in by the eye from a particular place.
> '*a fine view of the castle*'

— [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/view)

Caveat: I know this sounds simplistic, but I think it would describe the idea. That said, I have some problems interpreting "perpendicular" to the sight line on the vertical. For me, a perpendicular is drawn from a 90 degree angle.

The question has been edited, so I would like to also suggest

***overlook*** (noun)

> a commanding position or view.
> "he veered off the highway onto an overlook"

— [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overlook)

Comment: txs to @justin...my eyes are getting bad, so thanks for the edits

Comment: No problem, @Cascabel.

Answer (score 1):

The question is clear (despite the closers who said it lacks detail). One candidate is **elevation**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elevation)
>
> elevation: noun
>
> *the front or side of a building as shown on a drawing*
>
> *height above the surface of the earth, or an area that is higher than the surrounding land*

Merriam Webster also offers:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevation)
>
> the height to which something is elevated: such as
> a: *the angular distance of something above the horizon*

These definitions justify the use of *elevation* to describe the apparent height of a mountain above its surroundings, expressed either as a height by comparison with other features, or as an angle perceived by the eye when absolute heights are not known.

Hence: *... the best spot in this valley to enjoy an epic elevation from the riverbed to the summit ...*

Comment: 'The question is clear (despite the closers who say it lacks detail)' almost certainly fails to take into account the timeline here. A check on the edit to the question will probably at least make it plain that the choice of 'say' rather than 'said' is misleading. Comments, of course, cannot be adjusted later.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am grateful for that view and have altered accordingly. As an operational aside, how do I check the edits to questions? I see no access to the edit history, but perhaps this is merely because I have not yet progressed to such access. Or am I just missing the obvious?

Comment: @Anton Sorry, but you need to click on the [edited] section at the bottom of the Q...Edits for you have been available since like almost the month you got onboard.

Comment: @Anton: It is also accessible from the timeline; click on the little clock-like thing next to the question.

Comment: 'The question is clear (despite the closers who said it lacks detail)' might still be seen to fall far short of the 'The question has now been clarified (probably largely thanks to the comments of the closers requesting such clarification.'  'Despite the closers' is an ad hominem phrasing.

Comment: @Justin that is useful, but the list it shows isn't up-to-date.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Could you explain what you mean by "isn't up to date"? The last comment on the question is by you (currently) and it shows up in the timeline.

Comment: @Justin the last entry I can see was about an hour ago - ah I see, it's just the question comments, not answer comments, which have their own list.